# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate conditional field value based on update or insert..?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using `findOneAndUpdate` with `upsert: true` in the options.

I'd like to conditionally set a field based on whether the document will be updated or inserted.

```
const find = { email: 'me@me.com' }
const newDoc = { name: 'me', email: 'me@me.com', key: '???' }
const options = { new: true, upsert: true }
Accounts.findOneAndUpdate(find, newDoc, options)
```

When it's an update, I need to leave the `key` field alone, but when it's an insert I need to generate a new key.

Is this possible..?

Comment: [`$setOnInsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/setOnInsert/). It's in the documentation. And oddly comes up when you type in some relevant words from your title...

Comment: Perfect, thank you! ...and yes, this is a dup, however @JeremyThille answer to this question also works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a default in your Mongoose model.

For instance :

```
const generateKey = () => { 
    // ...
    return key
}

// in your Mongoose model
key : {
    type : String,
    default : generateKey
}
```

Then, don't specify the key in the document you're sending to Mongo :

```
const newDoc = { name: 'me', email: 'me@me.com' } // No key
```

So it will generate a key on insert, or leave it be otherwise.